# JAWS not reading table header from contents in IE

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have the below markup.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th tabIndex="0">Company</th>
    <th tabIndex="0">Contact</th>
    <th tabIndex="0">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using IE11 and JAWS18. When navigating with tabs, JAWS is not reading the table headers. When I tried with the same markup in chrome and JAWS, it is reading all the table headers.

I also tried specified aria-label for table headers, but no use.

```html
<th tabIndex="0" aria-label="Company">Company</th>
<th tabIndex="0" aria-lable="Contact">Contact</th>
<th tabIndex="0" aria-label="Country">Country</th>
```

Can someone please tell why JAWS18 could not read table headers in IE? It could not read either from the table headers contents or from aria-label in IE.
Also, is there any alternative for this?

Comment: You can use Microsoft's acccheckui.exe tool from the Windows 8.1 SDK to see how IE's presentation of the app differs from Chrome's.  It might be an IE limitation or a JAWS one.  Older versions of Chrome were pretty bad in their JAWS support, IE might be the same

Comment: Why are you giving the headers tab indexes?

Comment: In my scenario, I need a tabIndex for table header. On pressing tab, should move through the table headers. Is there a work around for the table header to be read out on tab with JAWS and IE.?

Answer (score 0):

Add a scope attribute to the header cells, e.g.

```
<th scope=“col”>Company</th>
```

This tells the screenreader what the relationship is between the header cells and other cells. You don’t need the tabindex or ARIA for this, just use the arrow keys to navigate instead of tabbing.

Comment: In my scenario, I need a tabIndex for table header. On pressing tab, should move through the table headers. Is there a work around for the table header to be read out on tab with JAWS and IE.?